# What wrong with BST

Tags: c++

I want to print all the key in BST. Why it printing only "the tree is empty" It just printing the tree is empty 2 times.
my coding first method is about creating a node to be a leaf and second is creating the leaf into the tree and thrid is printing the tree by inorder.
  If my coding is too bad can you fix it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class BST
{
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            int key;
            Node *left;
            Node *right;
        };
        Node* root;
        Node* createLeafPrivate(int key,Node* ptr);
        void addLeafPrivate(int key,Node* ptr);
        void printInoderPrivate(Node* ptr);
    public:
        BST():root(nullptr){}
        Node* createLeaf(int key);
        void addLeaf(int key);
        void printInorder();


};
BST::Node* BST::createLeaf(int key)
{
    Node* newNode=new Node();
    newNode->key=key;
    newNode->left=nullptr;
    newNode->right=nullptr;
    return newNode;
}
void BST::addLeaf(int key)
{
    addLeafPrivate(key,root);
}
void BST::addLeafPrivate(int key,Node* Ptr)
{
    if(root == nullptr)
        root=createLeaf(key);
    else if (key < Ptr->key)
    {
        if(Ptr->left != nullptr)
            addLeafPrivate(key,Ptr->left);
        else
            Ptr->left=createLeaf(key);
    }
    else if (key > Ptr->key)
    {
        if(Ptr->right != nullptr)
            addLeafPrivate(key,Ptr->right);
        else
            Ptr->right=createLeaf(key);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"The key "<<key<<"has already been added to the tree\n";
    }
}
void BST::printInorder()
{
    printInoderPrivate(root);
}
void BST::printInoderPrivate(Node* Ptr)
{
    if(root != nullptr)
    {
        if(Ptr->left != nullptr)
            printInoderPrivate(Ptr->left);
        std::cout<<Ptr->key<<" ";
        if(Ptr->right != nullptr)
            printInoderPrivate(Ptr->right);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"The tree is empty\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    BST myTree;
    std::cout<<"----Printing the empty tree----\n";
    myTree.printInorder();
    for(int i=16;i<=0;i--)
        myTree.addLeaf(i);
    std::cout<<"----Printing the data tree-----\n";
    myTree.printInorder();
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the loop in the `main` function.

Comment: If you do that for learning, fine, but in general keep in mind that there are `std::set` and `std::map`, which both implement a binary search tree as well – and use better algorithm to keep the tree balanced (usually a red-black-tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some more explicit help, i.e. a detailed version of the comment by Some programmer dude. I will however leave the last step to yourself to spot, in order to not spoil his obvious attempt to help you with a more long term perspective.

This loop inside your `main()`

```
for(int i=16;i<=0;i--)
    myTree.addLeaf(i);
```

will (the following is an example of the recommended "rubber duck debugging"):

- initialise i to 16
- execute the loop body as long as `i` is less or equal 0
- including to decrement `i`

Rethorical question as an additional hint:
So how often do you expect the loop body and the decrementing to be executed?